# rails internal server error when do ajax post

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes, internal-server-error

I'm a new Rails developer. So when I try send AJAX post request to my controller, I get 500 Internal server error. There is my Rails controller

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :index
    def index
      @auctions = Auction.last(5)
    end

    def rate
      @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])
      if current_user.rates_count > 0
         @auction.user = current_user
         @auction.save
         current_user.rates_count -= 1
         current_user.save
         @auction.user.login
      else
         'Error'
      end
    end
end
```

This is my application.js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".products-bet").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/rate',
        data: {'id': auct_id }
    });
});$(document).ready(function() {
$(".products-bet").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/rate',
        data: {'id': auct_id }
    });
});  });
```

And this is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
    root 'main#index'
    post 'rate', to: 'main#rate'
end
```

So, I can't understand what I do wrong.

Comment: Can you post your error log?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of things - that you get 500 error means it's probably routing correctly else, you would get a 404.  It could be that @auction is nil or current_user has no rates_count method or attribute

But it should be fairly easy to debug by looking @ your development.log file.  In general with ajax, you can debug easily by removing the "post" restriction on the call in routes, then just make the call by typing in the browser, so that the stack trace shows up on the browser.

You could also try to use the debugger to step through it.